# Sedlex installed by opam but not found by ocamlfind

Tags: macos, ocaml

Here is my problem : opam tells me that sedlex is installed, but ocamlfind cannot find it ;

(question already asked on the ocaml-beginners mailing list, as it received no answer I give it another try here)

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Ewan:Diasur ewan$ opam list
# Installed packages for system:
base-bigarray                 base  Bigarray library distributed with the OCaml compiler
base-threads                  base  Threads library distributed with the OCaml compiler
base-unix                     base  Unix library distributed with the OCaml compiler
camlp4               4.02.1+system  Camlp4 is a system for writing extensible parsers for programming languages
oasis                        0.4.5  Architecture for building OCaml libraries and applications
ocaml-data-notation         0.0.11  Store data using OCaml notation
ocamlfind                    1.5.5  A library manager for OCaml
ocamlify                     0.0.1  Include files in OCaml code
ocamlmod                     0.0.7  Generate OCaml modules from source files
ppx_tools                   0.99.2  Tools for authors of ppx rewriters and other syntactic tools
sedlex                      1.99.2  unicode-friendly lexer generator (successor of ulex, now based on -ppx inst
type_conv                112.01.01  Library for building type-driven syntax extensions
MacBook-Pro-de-Ewan:Diasur ewan$ ocamlfind ocamlc -c -package sedlex fowl.ml
ocamlfind: Package `sedlex' not found
```

I also tried re-installing but it changes nothing :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Ewan:Diasur ewan$ opam reinstall sedlex
The following actions will be performed:
  ↻  recompile sedlex 1.99.2

=-=- Gathering sources =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[sedlex] Archive in cache

=-=- Processing actions -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
⊘  removed   sedlex.1.99.2
∗  installed sedlex.1.99.2
Done.
MacBook-Pro-de-Ewan:Diasur ewan$ ocamlfind ocamlc -dsource -c -package sedlex fowl.ml
ocamlfind: Package `sedlex' not found
```

Also, ocamlfind list|grep sedlex yields the following :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Ewan:Diasur ewan$ ocamlfind list| grep sedlex
sedlex              (version: 1.99.2)
sedlex.ppx          (version: 1.99.2)
```

Comment: That's weird, to say the least. `opam reinstall sedlex` is no help ?

Comment: @Drup no, it changes absolutely nothing (I updated my post to explain this)

Comment: Did you do ``eval `opam config env` `` ?

Comment: and what about `ocamlfind list | grep sedlex`?

Comment: @Drup I just did eval `opam config env`, and it executed without doing anything in particular. Is it supposed to output something ?

Comment: I said ``eval `opam config env` ``. The eval is important. It's not supposed to print anything but it modifies your environment. You were told by opam to put that in your .profile/.bashrc to set up the env correctly. After doing that, ocamlfind should find your libraries.